# How can I show that $1/N$ expansion for large $N$ matrix models have a string theoretical perturbation expansion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, partition-function, matrix-model, large-n

While surfing through some further reading suggestions on string theory, I stumbled upon this slide from a talk by Nathan Seiberg. I wanted to derive the main argument by applying a perturbation expansion for this partition function, but I couldn't get my head around the concept of a phase space for $N$ by $N$ matrices. I am accustomed to the techniques of path integrals in QFT, but for this case I couldn't even move my pen. How can I learn more about matrix models and partition functions for matrices so that I can show that simple matrix models have a stringy perturbation expansion?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mentioned expansion of $\ln\mathcal{Z}$ is one of the basic statements for matrix models. If you are familiar with QFT, it is quite easy to investigate matrix models with help of the following notes/books/papers:

1. ["Random Matrices"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04430v2) by Eynard et. al. It is well-written book with many examples and useful facts. You can briefly review Chapter 1 and can find the mentioned expansion in Chapter 2.
2. ["Matrix Models and 2D String Theory"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410136v1). Here you can find the similar narration but with (in my opinion) more details about strings.
3. ["2D Gravity and Random matrices"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306153). It is the big and comprehensive book about matrix models and its relations to 2D gravity. You can use it as the handbook.
4. ["Applications of Random Matrices in Physics"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402045295). Finally, if you are intereted about different applications of matrix models in physics (for instance, QCD), you can check this book.

If it is needed, I can reproduce the derivation of free energy expansion, but I assume that references are more useful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Alexandrov! I believe with these references, I can reproduce the result on my own.